# Isolated subshells in bash

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a way to call a completely isolated subshell from a bash script? What I mean is that the subshell that is called will not have any inherited variables from its parent. This is essentially what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: Take a look on this repo! https://github.com/kusalananda/shell-toolbox

Answer (score 6):

```
env -i "$BASH" -c 'your code here'
```

Would start a new `bash` interpreter to interpret `your code here` in an initially empty environment.

As it's a new `bash` instance, it would not inherit the aliases, positional parameters, unexported variables, functions.

With the `env -i` it would also not inherit  the exported variables and functions (defined by the calling `bash` or possibly inherited from earlier on).

It would still inherit some other types of attributes that are preserved across fork and command execution like the `umask`, file descriptors open without the close-on-exec flag, limits, some signal dispositions (like a `trap '' INT` in the caller would also cause SIGINT to be ignored in the callee).

Answer (score 1):

The `env` command with the `-i` flag creates an empty environment

```
% env -i /bin/env
%
```

Now `bash` will create a set of variables itself, but these aren't inherited; that's just `bash` being `bash`

```
% env -i /bin/bash -c set
BASH=/bin/bash  
BASHOPTS=cmdhist:extquote:force_fignore:hostcomplete:interactive_comments:progcomp:promptvars:sourcepath
BASH_ALIASES=()
BASH_ARGC=()
BASH_ARGV=()
BASH_CMDS=()
BASH_EXECUTION_STRING=set
BASH_LINENO=()
BASH_SOURCE=()
BASH_VERSINFO=([0]="4" [1]="2" [2]="46" [3]="2" [4]="release" [5]="x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu")
BASH_VERSION='4.2.46(2)-release'
DIRSTACK=()
EUID=1000
GROUPS=()
HOSTNAME=myhost.local
HOSTTYPE=x86_64
IFS=$' \t\n'
MACHTYPE=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
OPTERR=1                          
OPTIND=1
OSTYPE=linux-gnu
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
PPID=12003
PS4='+ '
PWD=/tmp
SHELL=/bin/bash
SHELLOPTS=braceexpand:hashall:interactive-comments
SHLVL=1
TERM=dumb
UID=1000
_=/bin/bash
```

Different shells will create different variables; eg ksh93 and csh:

```
% env -i /bin/ksh -c set
ENV=.sh.ENV
FCEDIT=ed
HISTCMD=0
IFS=$' \t\n'
JOBMAX=0
KSH_VERSION=.sh.version
LINENO=1
MAILCHECK=600
OPTIND=1
PPID=12003
PS2='> '
PS3='#? '
PS4='+ '
PWD=/tmp
RANDOM=12790
SECONDS=0.000
SHELL=/bin/sh
SHLVL=1
TMOUT=0

% env -i /bin/csh -c set
argv    ()
cwd     /tmp
path    (/usr/bin /bin /usr/local/bin)
shell   /bin/csh
status  0

% env -i /bin/csh -c setenv
PWD=/tmp
```

Comment: Note that since `env -i bash` also unsets the `PATH` environment variable, that means that it will only work if `bash` can be found in the default libc search path. On older (and not so old) GNU/Linux systems, it would look for `bash` first in the current directory which would be potentially dangerous.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas If the PATH is set in one (read) startup file like in `/etc/profile`: no such problem.

Comment: @isaac, `env` doesn't read `/etc/profile`. That's the kind of file read by login shells. The problem here is that `env -i` wipe the environment, and then calls `execvp("bash", ...)` and `execvp()` looks for `bash` in a default PATH which for instance on Ubuntu 16.04 is `:/bin:/usr/bin`. If there you do `cd /tmp; ln -s /bin/echo bash; env -i bash -c uname`, you see `-c uname`, not `Linux` regardless of what `/etc/profile` contains.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks; I updated the answer to have full path to the command being run.